# Having trouble with Querying currentUser data, in Parse, to populate Table View ViewController using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

**I am fairly new to Parse**.. I am trying to query data of the current user and populate a table view in a 'User Profile' view controller. I am trying to display the current user's columns within a "Product" class.

Here is what I have...

```
class UserProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var userProductTableView: UITableView!


var userProductImagePNG = [PFFile]()
var userProductShortDescription = [String]()
var userProductTitle = [String]()
var userProductPrice = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    var userQuery = PFQuery(className: "Product")
    userQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    userQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (userProducts: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // success fetching objects
            for userProduct in userProducts! {

               println(userProducts?.count)
 }

        }else {

            println(error)
        }
```

Every time I try to run the app this is what it tells me...

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView
>   tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fa74b40fae0'

I do apologize if the question is not very clear. I am a first year programmer :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UITableView must have an object that acts as a data source and an object that acts as a delegate.  So in your case, it looks like you would want

```
self.delegate = self;
self.dataSource = self;
```

This means, that currentv view that you're on (self) is responsible for implementing the appropriate delegate and dataSource methods that will be called when the UITableView looks to populate its contents.

Than you can implement the appropriate delegate methods for UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate to fill in the appropriate information

Comment: Basically my view controller is "UserProfileVC", my table view is "userProductTableView", and my TV Cell is "UserProductTVCell". It is letting me pass userProductTableView.delegate = self; .... But not .dataSource.        It is saying "cannot assign a value of type "UserProfileViewVC" to a value of type "UITableViewDataSource?"

Comment: have you adopted the UITableViewDataSource protocol ?

Comment: I've tried, but it says my VC cannot conform to the protocol.

Comment: when you adopt the UITableViewDataSource, you also must implement the required methods in order to conform to it

Comment: Very true. Beginner's mistake. I will give it a try! Thnx.